# How do I go through the if, else statement again after making a change in one of the else ifs?

Tags: c#, if-statement

Here is my code. In if (currSum > flowersForOneWreath) I make currLiliesNum -= 2; and I want to go back to the if else statement and check again the currSum vs flowersForOneWreath, but in this case I go out of the while loop and no result is printed on the console.
Any ideas?
I tried to put continue; after currLiliesNum -= 2;, but nothing changed.

```
            var flowersForOneWreath = 15;
            var storedFlowersForLater = 0;
            var wreathsCount = 0;
            var wreathsNeeded = 5;

            while (liliesStack.Any())
            {
                var currLiliesNum = liliesStack.Peek();
                var currRosesNum = rosesStack.Peek();
                var currSum = currLiliesNum + currRosesNum;

                if (currSum > flowersForOneWreath)
                {
                    currLiliesNum -= 2;
                }
                else if (currSum < flowersForOneWreath)
                {
                    storedFlowersForLater += (currLiliesNum + currRosesNum);
                    liliesStack.Pop();
                    rosesStack.Pop();
                }
                else if (currSum == flowersForOneWreath)
                {
                    wreathsCount++;
                    liliesStack.Pop();
                    rosesStack.Pop();
                }

            }
```

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: Make the first if statement alone.  If (currSum > flowersForOne Wresth) {currLiliesNum -=2);
if(currSum< flowersForONeWresth){....}

Comment: Seems your Stack is empty after the first iteration that is the reason to out of the loop. Make sure your Stack has value and then you will continue your condition until the Stack size or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `continue` statement just skips to the next loop without executing any code after the statement within the enclosing loop. This means that the condition is checked again at the start of the next iteration, so the statement has no effect.

To sort this out, you can add a loop around your `if`/`else` statements to execute them multiple times with the updated value.

```cs
...

while (liliesStack.Any())
{
    var currLiliesNum = liliesStack.Peek();
    var currRosesNum = rosesStack.Peek();
    var currSum = currLiliesNum + currRosesNum;

    bool runLoop = true; // executes at least once

    while (runLoop)
    {
        runLoop = false; // prevent an infinite loop
        
        if (currSum > flowersForOneWreath)
        {
            currLiliesNum -= 2;
            // this will cause the loop to execute again
            runLoop = true;
            // you have else if afterwards, so a continue statement is not neccesary
        }
        else if (currSum < flowersForOneWreath)
        {
            storedFlowersForLater += (currLiliesNum + currRosesNum);
            liliesStack.Pop();
            rosesStack.Pop();
        }
        else if (currSum == flowersForOneWreath)
        {
            wreathsCount++;
            liliesStack.Pop();
            rosesStack.Pop();
        }
    }
}

...
```